# UiLabel text get cut off from Top

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

i have a [Expandable label](https://github.com/apploft/ExpandableLabel) that shows Bengali font , but it gets cut off from top, as you can in the image:
[image]

Here how i declared the properties :

```
@IBOutlet private weak var descriptionLabel: ExpandableLabel!
```

I tried different method but didn't help, Example:

```
descriptionLabel.lineBreakMode = .byCharWrapping
descriptionLabel.sizeToFit()
descriptionLabel.baselineAdjustment = .none
```

Someone please suggest how to solve that by not cutting off the text from top.

Constraints:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
descriptionLabel.clipsToBounds = false
```

This solves the problem

Answer (score 0):

the label's (vertical) content compression resistance priority was not high enough, setting it to required (1000) fixed it.

or a quick hack

```
 override public func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    var frame = self. descriptionLabel.frame
    frame.size.height += 1.0
    self.descriptionLabel.frame = frame
}
```

Comment: sorry but still getting the issue